Voltage spikes due to switching disturbing transistor switch circuit


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I want to interface a 5v logic signal to an input of a microcontroller (STM32G030) that operates at 3.3V. I made the attached circuit to detect the rising edge of the input 5v signal. However, whenever a nearby AC mains socket switch is flipped, I get an interrupt (I configured the input pin of the microcontroller to generate an interrupt on detection of a falling edge). Can anyone help me improve this circuit and avoid getting such false interrupt detections due to the voltage spikes?

Why are you not using just resistor divider (5 to 3v3) with some filtering capacitor? Seems transistor is no needed.

Do you use that 5V logic signal only as an occasional event, something to indicate a change from time to time, or is it going to be a data signal running into hundreds or thousands of pulses per second?

@EdinFifić, the 5v logic signal is to be used occasionally (as an indicator of a shortcircuit event).

@AmritPalSingh What I am trying to understand is if the event will last longer than a milli-second, why not make your MCU detect a LEVEL instead of an edge? That way you can use a capacitor to smooth out a nearby spike and prevent false triggering.

@EdinFifić, Thanks for your valuable feedback! I will certainly try this out.

@AmritPalSingh I have added an answer with the simplest schematic for you, it should work. P.S.: Sorry, I had misread what you want, editing my answer now. In the meantime, please provide a picture of your setup, I suspect you have long wire picking up the nearby disturbances.

@EdinFifić, since I'm still at the prototyping stage, your suspicion is correct, I currently have long wires connecting to the microcontroller.

Just as an information: Many pins of your microcontroller are 5V tolerant (only for digital input). Consider table 11+12 in the datasheet. Therefore, the additional circutry might not be required in the first place

The simplest circuit to get the falling edge for your circuit is the one below:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It can be used to either detect a relatively slow-falling edge, or a low level input when the 5V supply is off.
The only drawback is a small current flowing from 3.3V to the 5V rail, but in most cases it should not affect anything.
R1 value of 100k should be good enough for almost anything, but you can experiment with resistor values from 10k to 1M, keep that line very short to reduce the effect from nearby voltage/current spikes.
I don't know how much is your +5V rail loaded, you can experiment and see how much voltage will there be when you disconnect the 5V supply line.
P.S.: I have re-read your question and realized you want a falling edge when the 5V comes UP.
Here is a schematic for that:

simulate this circuit
C1 can be decreased to 100nF if it will be sufficient for detection by the MCU, or it can be increased if insufficient for detection.
